# Laravel:: DB transactions with multiple servers

Tags: database, laravel

How to do DB transactions with multiple servers.

I have 3 servers and am connecting to a central database when calls coming from multiple servers at the time Transaction failing.

Ex:
3 users requested from some data say 'data1'. at any time 'data1' should get only one user while we users calling from multiple servers multiple users getting same data

Please let me know how to solve this issue?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: *at any time 'data1' should get only one user while we users calling from multiple servers multiple users getting same data* I literally have no idea what this means. Can you specifiy your question a bit more?

Comment: Hi, I mean to say, at a time only one user can access DB row data.
Ex: User 1 is access DB and gets the ID-1 data and that is should not get by other users. Here what happening is. User1 and user2 are able to get the data even after adding the transaction because we calling from multiple servers. I hope this will clear.

Comment: Honest question, since I don't know: can more than user access the database at the exact same time than 1? I thought this was inherently impossible.

Comment: Are we talking database access or application-that-makes-use-of-database access?

Comment: Do you mean if 3 users request the same data only 1 should get it? How about using [InnoDB locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html)?